# Update from Laravel 5.1 to 5.2 has stopped PHPUnit from working

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-5

In the interest of keeping our project up-to-date and to take advantage of new development, we updated from Laravel 5.1 to 5.2 yesterday. After massaging our codebase for a few hours, everything seems to run as normal, except now the PHPUnit tests we have used extensively in 5.1 have now stopped. PHPUnit shows the first line to show it has initialised:

```
PHPUnit 4.8.24 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
```

But then freezes indefinitely. I've tried upgrading to a later version of PHPUnit (we were using `4.2.24`, and I tried moving to `5.3.2`, but with the same results).

There are no errors in the log unfortunately. I tried to remove all the tests to make sure PHPUnit runs without any tests, and it does so:

```
Time: 2.19 seconds, Memory: 4.25Mb
No tests executed!
```

This indicates that there might be something in my tests somewhere causing it, but I've gone right down to removing everything but a single test and the issue remains.

Does anyone know what might cause this in moving from 5.1 to 5.2? How would one go about debugging and getting these tests to run again?

We're using PHP version 5.6.13.

Config, for what it's worth:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
        backupStaticAttributes="false"
        bootstrap="bootstrap/autoload.php"
        colors="true"
        convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
        convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
        convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
        processIsolation="false"
        stopOnFailure="true">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
            <directory>./tests/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory suffix=".php">app/</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: What PHP version are you using?

Comment: @RossWilson Apologies, 5.6.13

Comment: I know of some issues with PHP7 but unfortunately nothing with 5.6.

Comment: Hi @dKen, I had the same before, because the laravel's testing API was changed from version [5.1](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.html) to [5.2](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.html) (check the API)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For you poor souls who get caught up in more Laravel madness, the issue here was that some configuration changed in `5.1` to `5.2`. In frustration, I rebuilt my config from the bottom up and things started to work again. Here's what I did:

1. Add a testing environment file called `.env.testing`.

Mine looks somewhat like this:

```
DB_CONNECTION="testing"

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=something_tests
DB_USERNAME=username
DB_PASSWORD=password

APP_DEBUG="true"
```

2. In your `phpunit.xml` file, in the `<php>` section, add `<env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>`, so it points to the aforementioned file.
3. Check your `config/database.php` file and make sure the `DB_CONNECTION` is defined and correct.

Once you're done, do the usual `php artisan config:clear`. I've also found that sometimes my testing database gets messed up if some tests fail during development, so occasionally I need to blast the whole thing away and rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same issue, and I solved by removing the use of DatabaseMigrations from my tests. If you have it there, try to remove it and run your tests again.

Comment: If I'm honest, I can't remember quite how I resolved this, but I didn't remove migrations. How do you test with a consistent DB without using migrations? EDIT: Actually, I think it was the way configurations changed in `5.1` to `5.2`. I rebuilt my testing config from the bottom up and documented it so I remembered in the future!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I didn't mean that I removed the migration files. I was referring to DatabaseMigrations trait https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/testing#resetting-the-database-after-each-test